# Run Smirnov test in Java

Tags: java, statistics, statistical-test

I'm trying to run a Smirnov test in Java, to see if two sets of data come from the same distribution. However, I am getting a "cannot find symbol" error. How to do I "construct" a Smirnov Test so as not get this error?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.*;
import jsc.independentsamples.SmirnovTest;
import jsc.*;

public class test{

  public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

    double[] array1 = {1.1,2.2,3.3};
    double[] array2 = {1.2,2.3,3.4};

    SmirnovTest test = SmirnovTest(array1, array2);

    test.getSP();

  }
}
```

Comment: First rule of asking for help: "Post the entire actual error message, using copy/paste. Do not paraphrase". Second rule: "When the message refers to a line number in your code, identify the line in question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible issues, not mutually exclusive and one of them is *definitely* an issue.

1. Your classpath is wrong. Make sure that `jsc.jar` is in your classpath.
2. You need to invoke the constructor for `SmirnovTest` by using an instance creation expression which requires the use of the keyword `new`.

That is

```
SmirnovTest test = new SmirnovTest(array1, array2);
                   ^^^
```

The second is *definitely* an issue with your code. Without using the keyword `new`, `javac` will interpret

```
SmirnovTest test = SmirnovTest(array1, array2);
```

as a method invocation and look for a method named `SmirnovTest` in the class `test`. You don't have it, so it will die with a `cannot find symbol` error, whether or *not* you have successfully imported `jsc.jar`.

Please fix the second if not also the first of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Here's the final code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import jsc.independentsamples.SmirnovTest;



public class test{



 public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {


double[] array1 = {1.1,2.2,3.3};
double[] array2 = {1.2,2.3,3.4};


SmirnovTest test = new SmirnovTest(array1, array2);

System.out.println(test.getSP());




 }

}
```

The output is: 1.0